# Can't subscribe to ReportBuilder report in SSRS 2008-r2

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

When a user tries to subscribe to a report created via ReportBuilder they receive the following error: "Subscriptions cannot be created because the credentials used to run the report are not stored, or if a linked report, the link is no longer valid."

As far as I can tell the credentials ARE being stored, but report server seems to be ignoring them.  We are able to subscribe to non-ReportBuilder reports using the same data source just fine.

We have been trying to track down the problem for several weeks now and haven't gotten anywhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The report uses a shared data source on its model. This is the only model defined on the server:
[image: Report Configuration]

The model uses the following data source defined on the server (this is the same data source that other reports use, and it's the only data source stored on the server.):
[image: Model Configuration]

The Data Source is set to store the credentials on the report server (you can see the results of testing the connection at the bottom of the screenshot):
[image: Data Source Configuration]

Comment: Is there a subreport? If that's the case, make sure that it also uses a datasource with stored credentials

Comment: No sub reports.  We get the same problem when we create a completely static simple report using the model.

Comment: You cannot subscribe to a Report Builder report that uses a model as a data source if the model contains model item security settings. Could this be the cause of your issues?

Comment: Turning off Model Item Security fixed the problem!  Thank you so much!  If you create an answer from this I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot subscribe to a Report Builder report that uses a model as a data source if the model contains model item security settings. Could this be the cause of your issue?

Comment: I have to wait 18 more hours before the site will allow to award the bounty.